# How to prepare glacial acetic acid from sodium acetate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, purification

What would be the most practical process to prepare glacial acetic acid from sodium acetate?

I'm thinking to react the sodium acetate with an acid to convert the solution to acetic acid and sodium salt but I'm not sure of the most practical way to proceed from here without distillation (which seems impractical).

I think solvent extraction (using a protonated solvent such as $\ce{CH2Cl2}$) then removal of the solvent would be a way but I'm not sure.

I would like to hear from someone who's done it before.

Comment: I do not think there is an insoluble sodium salt and distillation of glacial acetic acid just sound incredibly dangerous and horrifying.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with distillation of acetic acid per se, so it's a way to go as long as it happens under fume hood. Distillation of bromine or nitric acid is way more dangerous and still is used.

Comment: It forms the azeotrope with water which is difficult to remove.

Comment: @Joel Same with nitric acid. Still, it is prepared by distillation from reaction mixture of sulfuric acid and potassium nitrate. Same is probably applicable to acetic acid. Or, in case you are not brave enough, the traditional way is a way to go (freezing the azeotrope)

Comment: I'll take that on board thanks , I'd like to find a way to do bit by solvent extraction.  I'd rather distill a suitable solvent than the actual acid it's much quicker. It's not a matter of being brave enough I understand the variables its about practicality.

Comment: Why would you *want* to prepare acetic acid from sodium acetate anyway? It’s cheap as sand, isn’t it?

Comment: No not really ! I have a lot of sodium acetate and instead of throwing it out I wanted to see if I could to something with it...

Comment: @Joel even so, the ingredients and equipment you need to covert sodium acetate back to glacial acetic acid will probably cost you more than just buying some glacial acetic acid. Don't waste time, effort and money on futile stuff unless it is fun (which this won't be).

Comment: @matt_black. I know what your saying but it's not helping . I don't want to buy it that's the whole point I don't really need it.

Comment: I would oxidized ethanol if I really needed to synthesize it for something.

Comment: There is a rumor around my lab that if you freeze vinegar at a very specific temperature, than get rid of the water ice, than thaw it, you could in theory extract Glacial Acetic Acid, but again, its just a rumor, and I haven't tested it.

Comment: You would only have to get the acetic acid down to below 15c and above 10c to prevent any water from freezing. Even though the melting temp for water is 0c, it is always safer because of the azeotrope to just keep it above 10c.

Comment: Dichloromethane is not a "protonated" solvent.

Comment: Matt_black lol think I meant polar